# Cannot get animated text to display using Textualizer

Tags: jquery, css, html

I was trying a simple demo here: [my attempt at using textualizer](http://alexandria83.etcserver.com/~seansws/sandbox/texutalizer/)

based on the simple documentation on http://kiro.me/textualizer/

For some reason the effect seems to be working in the console, but the text is not transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your example works fine, but your selection, where the text is put, doesn't have a height, so it just takes 0px. Thats why you don't see the transforming text. Just define a height to it and you can see it.

[image: Scrreenshot of text visualization with height set to 500px]

BTW: thanks for the link, it looks interesting.

Comment: Woo! It works now. How could I forget the height:) Thanks!

http://alexandria83.etcserver.com/~seansws/sandbox/texutalizer/